# wordpress-java API | How get link of media attachment of post?

Tags: android, wordpress

I have developed an Android application to get data of a `Wordpress-powered blog`.
I would like to download the picture attached to a post.
My app retrieves the post but I don't find where or which method allows to get the link.
Is it possible to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To this with wordpress API, it's easy to get with `get_attachment_url` like:

```
<?php $url = wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID, 'thumbnail') ); ?>
<img src="<?php echo $url ?>" />
```

But for this you'll need to query the `wp_posts` table for a post type of `attachment`. 
The trick is to first get the attachment ID that you need to grab.

The featured image attachment id is stored in the `post_meta` table, with the meta_key `_thumbnail_id`.

Use that post id to find the post meta with meta_key `_wp_attachment_metadata`.

The value of that is a serialized array with keys `thumb`, `file`, `width`, `height`, `sizes` (an array), and `image_meta` (an array).

The `file` value is relative to the uploads directory for the WP install, and points to the original full-sized image. **You should be able to calculate the URL from that by generating attachment permalink.**

`sizes` has an image size as its key (e.g., 'small', 'medium', 'large', 'thumbnail'), and the value is an array with keys `file`, `height`, and `width`.

But definitely, you will require to do some work here....

Answer (score 0):

Function [`get_the_post_thumbnail`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_post_thumbnail) will give you the featured image for a post.

Comment: Thank you your answers, but I code in java on android, is on my android application I want to retrieve the link.thank you your answers, but I code in java on android is on my android application I want to retrieve the link.
I speak of this API : http://code.google.com/p/wordpress-java/